# How can I import wallet.dat file to Bitcoin ABC wallet without downloading whole blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, ecash

I keep my BTC in Bitcoin Core wallet. I would like to start using my BCC but full node is downloading whole blockchain. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a BCC full node, you can use an SPV wallet like [Electrum](https://electrum.org/) (see instructions on BCC [here](https://electrum.org/bcc.txt)).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support BCC without downloading blockchain, there are two options.

### 1) Bitcoin ABC + pruning

Pruning allows your Bitcoin-Qt/BU/ABC to work as a node without downloading the entire blockchain.

See this on how to prune: [Can Bitcoin-Qt be configured to trim the blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20000/can-bitcoin-qt-be-configured-to-trim-the-blockchain/38847#38847)

### 2) Electron Cash

[Electron Cash](http://www.electroncash.org) is the changed version of Electrum SPV client with BCC support. As it's a SPV client, ----it won't download the entire blockchain-----, as change suggested by [@Pieter Wuille](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/208/pieter-wuille), SPV clients do download the blockchain, they just don't store entire blocks, they keep only the required parts.

Comment: Pruning does not mean you don't download the chain; only that you don't store it after validation.