# How can I prune my Bitcoin Core correctly? The other way did not work for me. Have I done any unnoticed mistake?

Tags: pruning

Saving the entire blockchain in my computer is taking mi a lot of space. I looked in this forum for a solution and I saw that there was an option to prune the node and save a lot of space.
I followed the instructions, I went to the Bitcoin data directory, I created a file there and called it "bitcoin.conf" and I wrote "-prune=1100" in it.
Nothing I expected happened, the space it took remained the same, it only started downloading a new blockchain called "testnet".
Have I done something wrong? And how can I fix it in order to save space?
My version of Bitcoin Core is v0.14..2

PS: Latter, I have discovered that, in fact, I have three Bitcoin data directories, and suddenly I have doubts about in which of them shall I place my "bitcoin.conf".
Is having three directory data how it shall be? And in which of them shall I place my "bitcoin.conf".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post exactly the contents of your bitcoin.conf file? Can you also post the command that you are using to start Bitcoin Core with (if you are on windows, right click the shortcut you are using and copy the contents of the Target box).

Comment: Can you post exactly the contents of your bitcoin.conf file? prune=1100
And I am using Windows 10. I am not a computer expert so I do not understand the rest of the question.

Comment: In the config file you need to use "prune=1100", not "-prune=1100". Is that the problem?

Comment: I have tried both ways and it hasn´t work in any of both. Just now I have "prune=1100"

Comment: Some questions have multiple answers.  Since my answer is no longer identified as being correct, it will not be subject to mistake by others in thinking that I have answered your question.  In the mean time, I am trying to see if I just need to add one more step to mine to make it work or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Bitcoin-Qt be configured to trim the blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20000/can-bitcoin-qt-be-configured-to-trim-the-blockchain)

Comment: Have you restarted Bitcoin Core after adding the line to config? It is a startup parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description it sounds to me that you may have edited your configuration file while Bitcoin Core was already running.

`prune=1100` is a **startup parameter**. It will take effect once you restart the program.

1. If you add a parameter to the startup instructions,  parameters start with a dash (`-prune=1100`), e.g.:

   ```
   "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -prune=1100
   ```

   Please make sure you use the correct path for the actual directory you installed Bitcoin to.
2. If you add it to the configuration, the parameter must be listed without a dash in the `bitcoin.conf`:

   ```
   prune=1100
   ```

   If you're unsure how to locate your Bitcoin data directory, please see: [Where is the configuration file of Bitcoin-Qt kept?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/11190/5406)

There is **no need to manually delete any files** from your Bitcoin directory, or to start over the initial blockchain download to enable pruning.
You merely need to restart Bitcoin Core after you've edited the `bitcoin.conf`. If you don't know how to restart a program, you may find it simpler to shut down and restart your computer.

Comment: How do I access to the startup instructions? And, is restarting the program, only, to close and open the program again (becouse I have already tried that)? Or, do I have to do something more?

Comment: Yes, go to the menu, quit the program, start it again. At this point the `bitcoin.conf` gets used to initialize the program. Note that the standard "close window" operation is probably just hiding the program. You have to quit it, not hide it.

Comment: I have tried in different ways, I am sure I have restarted Bicoin Core, but it did not work. Now, I have discovered a new things that I will edit in the question.

Comment: @AnderAristondo Use the folder from the first picture. Put the `bitcoin.conf` file there.